# How can I use Perl's format function?

Tags: function, perl, format

I'm learning Perl formatting by following the tutorial at *[Perl - Formats](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_formats.htm)*, but when I type their example into my IDE:

```
format EMPLOYEE =
===================================
@<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< @<<
$name $age
@#####.##
$salary
===================================
.

select(STDOUT);
$~ = EMPLOYEE;

@n = ("Ali", "Raza", "Jaffer");
@a  = (20,30, 40);
@s = (2000.00, 2500.00, 4000.000);

$i = 0;
foreach (@n) {
   $name = $_;
   $age = $a[$i];
   $salary = $s[$i++];
   write;
}
```

I get the error:

```
Scalar found where operator expected at .\qb.pl line 7, near "$name $age"
        (Missing operator before $age?)
syntax error at .\qb.pl line 7, near "$name $age"
Execution of .\qb.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

I'm using Perl 5, version 30, Subversion 2 (v5.30.2) built for *MSWin32-x64-multi-thread*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I run your code on 5.24, I see this warning message:

> Use of comma-less variable list is deprecated at...

which points to the `$name $age` line as well.

When I enable [diagnostics](https://perldoc.perl.org/diagnostics.html), I get this explanation:

```
(D deprecated) The values you give to a format should be
separated by commas, not just aligned on a line.
```

When I add the comma as follows:

```
$name,$age
```

the warning goes away, and I get this output:

```
===================================
Ali                     20
  2000.00
===================================
===================================
Raza                    30
  2500.00
===================================
===================================
Jaffer                  40
  4000.00
===================================
```

---

This warning became an error in 5.28, according to [perl5280delta](https://perldoc.perl.org/perl5280delta.html).

Answer (score 3):

Your first mistake was in thinking that formats were a useful tool that would solve your problem. Formats have been largely ignored for almost as long as I've been using Perl. You'll probably find that using [Perl6::Form](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl6::Form) is a better approach.

Your second mistake was in thinking that Tutorials Point was a good place to get information about anything. The tutorials there are written by people who seem to know next to nothing about their subject and (as you have seen here) the examples are riddled with typos that makes them next to useless.

If you're determined to use Perl formats, then the [perlform](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlform.html) manual page would be the best place to start.

Comment: Oh really? Why are they ignored? Also, what would be a better source to learn?

Comment: They're largely ignored as they're too hard to use and not very flexible. If you're looking for better Perl tutorials then [learn.perl.org](https://learn.perl.org/tutorials/) is a good place to start.

Comment: I don't think formats are hard to use, and they can be very useful at producing nice pretty-printed output, but, yeah, Perl6::Form is more flexible and has a lot more formatting options available for different types of data than strings.

Comment: Unfortunately, Tutorials Point has very good SEO.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the following code sample is easier to read. The output is also easier to comprehend at a quick glance:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my($name, $age, $salary);

while(<DATA>) {
    ($name, $age, $salary) = split;
    write;
}

format STDOUT_TOP =
 Employee               Age      Salary
----------------------------------------
.

format STDOUT =
 @<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< @<<   @#####.##
$name, $age, $salary
.

__DATA__
Ali        20    2000.00
Raza       30    2500.00
Jaffer     40    4000.00
```

#### Output

```
 Employee               Age      Salary
----------------------------------------
 Ali                     20      2000.00
 Raza                    30      2500.00
 Jaffer                  40      4000.00
```

There are many ways to provide input data. One of them is a hash to keep related data.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %employees = (
    Ali       => { age => 20, salary => 2000.00},
    Raza      => { age => 30, salary => 2500.00},
    Jaffer    => { age => 40, salary => 4000.00}
    );

my($name, $age, $salary);

for $name (sort keys %employees) {
    ($age, $salary) = @{$employees{$name}}{qw/age salary/};
    write;
}

format STDOUT_TOP =
 Employee               Age      Salary
----------------------------------------
.

format STDOUT =
 @<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< @<<   @#####.##
$name, $age, $salary
.
```

#### Output

```
 Employee               Age      Salary
----------------------------------------
 Ali                     20      2000.00
 Jaffer                  40      4000.00
 Raza                    30      2500.00
```